# Html.BeginForm redirect with jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, html.beginform

We have an Html.BeginForm where after it's been submitted a RedirectResult is returned from the controller. This works fine for desktops, but for mobile devices, it is always submitted as an ajax request, which means the redirect doesn't work.

I've tried adding data-ajax="false" to both the form and the submit button, but it's still an ajax request by the time it gets to the controller. I've looked at quite a few posts but not found a useful answer for this scenario.

I'm not terribly keen on returning a script changing window.location.href from the controller. Is there a way to force the request to arrive as non-ajax at the controller (as mentioned, I tried data-ajax="false")?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, adding 'data_role="none"' to the Html.BeginForm HTML attributes fixed it for us.